# How to boot into Ubuntu 14.04 after installing win 8.1

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot

I have installed windows 8.1 after Ubuntu 14.04 and now I can't boot into Ubuntu. How can I fix that? I can't boot at all, so I was thinking about using somehow the dvd with Ubuntu or something like that?

Answer (score 1):

By installing Windows 8 after Ubuntu you have overwritten GRUB (Ubuntus default Bootmanger) in the MBR (Master Boot Record) and need to reinstall it. A good manual to do this can be found [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair).