# Unable to boot upuntu after installing windows

Tags: linux, windows-10, ubuntu

I've installed windows 10, and now I can't open ubuntu and do my usual work. I've searched for the problem but I found solutions that need an ubuntu cd to fix the problem using Linux commands. but I can't have it now. Is there any way to fix the problem using windows?!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to boot into Ubuntu 14.04 after installing win 8.1](https://superuser.com/questions/817221/how-to-boot-into-ubuntu-14-04-after-installing-win-8-1)

Comment: Before UEFI became the standard, [EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/) used to be able to configure the Windows boot loader to include booting Linux partitions, but I don't know if it's still possible. I have no idea why why you can't run an Ubuntu Live Boot disc, but this would be the recommended approach, and `boot-repair` makes the job pretty straightforward (you may need to install it with `apt` if it's not already on the Live Boot disc).